# Stemming text located in a list

Tags: python, list, edit, stemming

```
import re
import sys
stop=set(['biti','jesam','budem','sam','jesi','budeš','si','jesmo','budemo','smo','jeste','budete','ste','jesu','budu','su','bih','bijah','bjeh','bijaše','bi','bje','bješe','bijasmo','bismo','bjesmo','bijaste','biste','bjeste','bijahu','biste','bjeste','bijahu','bi','biše','bjehu','bješe','bio','bili','budimo','budite','bila','bilo','bile','ću','ćeš','će','ćemo','ćete','želim','želiš','želi','želimo','želite','žele','moram','moraš','mora','moramo','morate','moraju','trebam','trebaš','treba','trebamo','trebate','trebaju','mogu','možeš','može','možemo','možete'])


def istakniSlogotvornoR(niz):
    return re.sub(r'(^|[^aeiou])r($|[^aeiou])',r'\1R\2',niz)

def imaSamoglasnik(niz):
    if re.search(r'[aeiouR]',istakniSlogotvornoR(niz)) is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def transformiraj(pojavnica):
    for trazi,zamijeni in transformacije:
        if pojavnica.endswith(trazi):
            return pojavnica[:-len(trazi)]+zamijeni
    return pojavnica

def korjenuj(pojavnica):
    for pravilo in pravila:
        dioba=pravilo.match(pojavnica)
        if dioba is not None:
            if imaSamoglasnik(dioba.group(1)) and len(dioba.group(1))>1:
                return dioba.group(1)
    return pojavnica

if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)!=3:
        print 'Usage: python Croatian_stemmer.py input_file output_file'
        print 'input_file should be an utf8-encoded text file which is then tokenized, stemmed and written in the output_file in a tab-separated fashion.'
        sys.exit(1)
    output_file=open(sys.argv[2],'w')
    pravila=[re.compile(r'^('+osnova+')('+nastavak+r')$') for osnova, nastavak in [e.decode('utf8').strip().split(' ') for e in open('rules.txt')]]
    transformacije=[e.decode('utf8').strip().split('\t') for e in open('transformations.txt')]
    for token in re.findall(r'\w+',open(sys.argv[1]).read().decode('utf8'),re.UNICODE):
        if token.lower() in stop:
            output_file.write((token+'\t'+token.lower()+'\n').encode('utf8'))
            continue
        output_file.write((token+'\t'+korjenuj(transformiraj(token.lower()))+'\n').encode('utf8'))
    output_file.close()
```

I've downloaded a stemmer for the Croatian language. Now I learned that it's called/runned like "python input outpout" but I need this for stemming text data in my list. How would I need to edit the code so I could run it on a list, without saving my list to a text document?

Comment: Do you have a sample input and output file to test?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    open(sys.argv[1]).read().decode('utf8') as your input list
```

your expected result is this one:

```
  (token+'\t'+korjenuj(transformiraj(token.lower()))+'\n').encode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? Just add these functions before `if __name__ == "__main__":`

```
def fromListToList(wordlist):
    outputList = []
    global pravila, transformacije
    pravila=[re.compile(r'^('+osnova+')('+nastavak+r')$') for osnova, nastavak in [e.decode('utf8').strip().split(' ') for e in open('rules.txt')]]
    transformacije=[e.decode('utf8').strip().split('\t') for e in open('transformations.txt')]
    for token in wordlist:
        if token.lower() in stop:
            outputList.append((token+'\t'+token.lower()+'\n').encode('utf8'))
            continue
        outputList.append((token+'\t'+korjenuj(transformiraj(token.lower()))+'\n').encode('utf8'))
    return outputList


def fromListToFile(wordlist, output_file):
    global pravila, transformacije
    pravila=[re.compile(r'^('+osnova+')('+nastavak+r')$') for osnova, nastavak in [e.decode('utf8').strip().split(' ') for e in open('rules.txt')]]
    transformacije=[e.decode('utf8').strip().split('\t') for e in open('transformations.txt')]
    for token in wordlist:
        if token.lower() in stop:
            output_file.write((token+'\t'+token.lower()+'\n').encode('utf8'))
            continue
        output_file.write((token+'\t'+korjenuj(transformiraj(token.lower()))+'\n').encode('utf8'))
    output_file.close()
```

You can then import these functions in the file that you are generating the `wordlist`.

Note: I added the `global pravila, transformacije` because you are changing these lists in a function which are used in the other functions, hence they have to be `global`.